# Is it possible to fetch pc details from HTML page?

Tags: html

Hi I have a vbscript to fetch computer details like ram, OS version and so on.

Can you use that same thing in a HTML and fetch? Is any website available to check the those?

Comment: You may try HTA.

Comment: This would be an incredible security flaw if possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. Browsers expose extremely limited sets of information to every website their users happen to visit.